# How to make UITextField invisible/hide in IOS?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

In my app I have a shipping page and it contains two shipping address (shipping address1 and shipping address2) but I want to hide shipping address2 UITextField from code.

Please assist what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

To hide a textfield you can do this.

`txtFieldname.hidden = YES;`

Comment: Thanks Saheb, please tell me where i need to write this code means in which file?

Comment: Write this code in the `viewDidLoad` method of the Shipping Page View Controller.

Comment: Thanks Once again Saheb

Comment: i did that but UItxtFieild still showing. what i noticed that now textfield is not  editable and its hide the placeholder but blank UItxtfield still showing

Comment: Please check if the outlets are properly connected.

Comment: prntscr.com/adm75t please check the screenshot -i check outlets are ok